# How to prevent to create same url of post, if the previous was deleted?

Tags: posts, urls

Let's say I'm creating a post, it's URL will be:

```
www.example.com/posts/test-article
```

so far so good. Then, I delete it and also remove from trash bin.
Again, I create with the same title, and the URL will be:

```
www.example.com/posts/test-article
```

that's no good, I would like to get:

```
www.example.com/posts/test-article1
```

and so on. How to achieve that?

Comment: Just don't fully delete it (aka keep it trash bin)?

Comment: I was hoping there's a built-in solution.